# how to deploy the spring boot war on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat9, java-17, spring-boot-maven-plugin, postgres-14

I am trying to make the war file of the spring boot application in vs code using this command
mvn clean
mvn clean install
or
mvn clean install
or
mvn package

when i am deploying the war on tomcat and check into the browser and hit this url http://localhost:8080/welcome but tomcat started and my welcome routes not working it gives me the error

### pom.xml:

### application.properties:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cghs2test

when i deploying the war on tomcat my controller not hit
this is my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for building the tomcat war:
tomcat9.x - spring boot 2.x
dependecy tomcat
pom.xml
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-tomcat
tomcat-embed-core
thymleaf(opt)